# Why are taxes calculated incorrectly when "other amounts" enabled on contribution page?

Tags: taxes

CiviCRM 4.6.5, Wordpress 4.2.3

When I create a contribution page, I choose the financial type on which there is my taxes financial account linked.

The amount that the user can pay is decided by the user. So there is only "Allow other amounts enabled".

The tax financial account have a 14.975% rate.

When I put my page online and I try to make a contribution, I get a tax amount of 0.15% instead of 14.975%.

When I make a contribution manually with the same financial type, the taxes are calculated the right way.

If I put a precise amount with "Allow other amounts" disabled, the taxes are also calculated the right way.

Thanks for helping!

[image]

[image]

Whatever amount I put, the "Total tax amount" is equal to the Tax rate.

[image]

Comment: I managed to reproduce this on the demo site (http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&action=preview) By entering a 20$ donation in the "other amounts" field, CiviCRM calculated 0.15$ of taxes (for a 15% tax rate).

Comment: Created an issue here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16960

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Hope it will be fixed for the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is still unresolved, please help!

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17034

Answer (score 3):

This patch solved my issue by using a real priceset:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6520/files

Details here:

[Contribution forms with numerical quantities is not taxed properly](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/contribution-forms-with-numerical-quantities-is-not-taxed-properly)

Thanks!