# Contribution forms with numerical quantities is not taxed properly

Tags: civicontribute, taxes

We've got a 14.975% tax rate in the province of Quebec in Canada.

the taxes are rounded to the 2nd decimal so we lose information.

The taxes should be calculated on the subtotal instead of the unit price.

Thanks for helping!

The calculation is now (100*(1+0.15)) but should be (100*1)*1.14975

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This patch has solved my problem:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6520/files

PriceField tax_amount should not be rounded