# Taxes on "Allow other amounts" calculated on $1

Tags: civicontribute, taxes

This was noted back in 2015 I see ([Why are taxes calculated incorrectly when "other amounts" enabled on contribution page?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/why-are-taxes-calculated-incorrectly-when-other-amounts-enabled-on-contributio)). It doesn't seem like it would be hard to fix, but here we are almost 5 years later and the problem persists. It works in a price set, so there is a workaround, but it's a little uglier there when used for simple scenarios.

In this case, the tax rate is 13%. Calculated properly if fixed options are provided below, but calculated on 1 if the "allow other amounts" is checked and the box is used. I assume it is using the same logic that it does in a price set where it sets the value to $1 and then uses the box as a quantity. However, the tax calculation step is seemingly performed too soon.
Any chance it could be fixed? Happy to take a pointer to the related file(s) to have a look for myself.

[image: settings page]
[image: confirmation page]

Comment: Oh that’s not good! If you’re using Drupal I can show you how to work around this quickly with webform civicrm module.

Comment: Thanks Karin, not sure how I missed this. I'm using Wordpress I'm afraid. Is your fix CMS dependant?

Comment: With Webform CiviCRM module you can get very good control over the Financial Types per line item (Financial Types trigger the GST calculations). That module is a Drupal module though.